# Can't import the named export 'USER_REGISTER_REQUEST' (imported as 'USER_REGISTER_REQUEST') from default-exporting module (only default export is

Tags: javascript

Can't import the named export 'USER_REGISTER_REQUEST' (imported as 'USER_REGISTER_REQUEST') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

i am expecting here exporting default with out error...can any one help to me

Comment: You need to share how you import export these modules. Error says that only default export is available, which means that you are trying to do more than that